# Gitlab CI Runner fails to push image to container registry - unexpected HTTP status: 200 OK

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, rpmbuild, gitlab-runner

### Introduction to problem

Hi, i deployed Gitlab on Rocky Linux 8 VM and Gitlab-runner on RHEL 9 VM  and custom self-signed CA.

Gitlab is up and running and jobs can be picked up with the runners successfully.

I want to create a custom docker image and push it to my container registry that is hosted in Gitlab (not external registry).

***Dockerfile in Gitlab.***

[image: Dockerfile to create an image that has all rpmbuild tools needed to build a rpm package]

***.gitlab-ci.yml***

```
build image:
image: docker:20.10.17
cache: []
services:
    - name: docker:20.10.17-dind
script:
    - echo $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER $CI_REGISTRY --password-stdin
    - docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE .
    - echo $GITLAB_REGISTRY_API_URL
    - echo $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
```

### Job fails

When the job gets triggered with the above **.gitlab-ci.yml** file then it fails by *retrying* to push the image and at the end with the error `received unexpected HTTP status: 200 OK`

[image: received unexpected HTTP status: 200 OK]

### Output of some relevant information/configuration to help debug or reproduce the problem

***on Server hosting Gitlab (Rocky 8)***

**/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb**

```
    [root@magnaslab nginx]# grep -v '^#\|^$' /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
external_url 'https://gitlab.magnas.com'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_default_theme'] = 1
gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['prevent_ldap_sign_in'] = false
 gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load <<-'EOS'
   main: # 'main' is the GitLab 'provider ID' of this LDAP server
     label: 'magnas'
     host: 'DC01.magnas.com'
     port: 389
     uid: 'sAMAccountName'
     encryption: 'plain' # "start_tls" or "simple_tls" or "plain"
     active_directory: true
     allow_username_or_email_login: true
     lowercase_usernames: true
     base: ''
     group_base: ''
     admin_group: ''
     sync_ssh_keys: false
EOS
registry_external_url 'https://gitlab.magnas.com'
registry['env'] = {
 "REGISTRY_HTTP_RELATIVEURLS" => true
}
registry_nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.magnas.com.crt"
registry_nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.magnas.com.key"
gitlab_rails['registry_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['registry_host'] = "gitlab.magnas.com"
gitlab_rails['registry_port'] = "80"
registry['enable'] = true
registry['username'] = "registry"
registry['env'] = {
   'SSL_CERT_DIR' => "/opt/gitlab/embedded/ssl/certs/"
}
registry['autoredirect'] = true
nginx['enable'] = true
nginx['client_max_body_size'] = '250m'
nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
nginx['redirect_http_to_https_port'] = 80
nginx['ssl_client_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.magnas.com.crt"
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.magnas.com.crt"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.magnas.com.key"
nginx['listen_addresses'] = ["0.0.0.0", "[::]"]
nginx['listen_port'] = 443
registry_nginx['enable'] = true
registry_nginx['listen_https'] = true
registry_nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
letsencrypt['enable'] = false # GitLab 10.5 and 10.6 require this option
external_url "https://gitlab.magnas.com"   # Must use https protocol
letsencrypt['contact_emails'] = ['xxxx@magnas.com' 'xxx@magnas.com'] # This should be an array of email addresses to add as contacts
```

**/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-http.conf**

```
        ## Redirects all HTTP traffic to the HTTPS host
    server {
      listen 0.0.0.0:80;
      listen [::]:80;
    
      server_name gitlab.magnas.com;
      server_tokens off; ## Don't show the nginx version number, a security best practice
    
    
      location / {
        return 301 https://gitlab.magnas.com:443$request_uri;
      }
    
      # health checks configuration
      include /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-health.conf;
    
      access_log  /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log gitlab_access;
      error_log   /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_error.log error;
    }

server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:443 ssl http2;


  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;


  server_name gitlab.magnas.com;
  server_tokens off; ## Don't show the nginx version number, a security best practice

  ## Increase this if you want to upload large attachments
  ## Or if you want to accept large git objects over http
  client_max_body_size 250m;

  ## Strong SSL Security
  ## https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html & https://cipherli.st/
  ssl_certificate /etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.magnas.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.magnas.com.key;
  ssl_client_certificate /etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.magnas.com.crt;

  # GitLab needs backwards compatible ciphers to retain compatibility with Java IDEs
  ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-GCM-SHA384';
  ssl_protocols  TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
  ssl_session_cache  shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_tickets off;
  ssl_session_timeout  1d;


  ## Real IP Module Config
  ## http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html

  ## HSTS Config
  ## https://www.nginx.com/blog/http-strict-transport-security-hsts-and-nginx/
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000";

  # Rails sets a default policy of strict-origin-when-cross-origin, so
  # hide that and just send the one we've configured for nginx
  proxy_hide_header Referrer-Policy;
  add_header Referrer-Policy strict-origin-when-cross-origin;

## Individual nginx logs for this GitLab vhost
  access_log  /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log gitlab_access;
  error_log   /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_error.log error;

  if ($http_host = "") {
    set $http_host_with_default "gitlab.magnas.com";
  }

  if ($http_host != "") {
    set $http_host_with_default $http_host;
  }

  gzip on;
  gzip_static on;
  gzip_comp_level 2;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  gzip_min_length 250;
  gzip_proxied no-cache no-store private expired auth;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/json;

  ## https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
  ## Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
  proxy_read_timeout      3600;
  proxy_connect_timeout   300;
  proxy_redirect          off;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;

  proxy_set_header Host $http_host_with_default;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;

  location ~ (/api/v\d/jobs/\d+/artifacts$|\.git/git-receive-pack$|\.git/gitlab-lfs/objects|\.git/info/lfs/objects/batch$) {
    proxy_cache off;
    proxy_pass http://gitlab-workhorse;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
  }

  location /-/grafana/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
  }

  location = /-/kubernetes-agent/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8150/;
  }

  location /-/kubernetes-agent/k8s-proxy/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8154/;
  }

  # health checks configuration
  include /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-health.conf;

  location / {
    proxy_cache off;
    proxy_pass  http://gitlab-workhorse;
  }

  location /assets {
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    proxy_cache gitlab;
    proxy_pass  http://gitlab-workhorse;
  }

  error_page 404 /404.html;
  error_page 500 /500.html;
  error_page 502 /502.html;
  location ~ ^/(404|500|502)(-custom)?\.html$ {
    root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;
    internal;
  }
```

**/var/log/gitlab/nginx/error.log**

```
/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-http.conf:34
2022/08/02 08:58:41 [emerg] 3484915#0: no "ssl_certificate" is defined for the "listen ... ssl" directive in /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-http.conf:34
2022/08/02 08:58:42 [emerg] 3484932#0: no "ssl_certificate" is defined for the "listen ... ssl" directive in /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-http.conf:34
2022/08/02 08:58:43 [emerg] 3485005#0: no "ssl_certificate" is defined for the "listen ... ssl" directive in /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-http.conf:34
2022/08/02 08:58:44 [warn] 3485019#0: conflicting server name "gitlab.magnas.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2022/08/02 08:58:44 [warn] 3485019#0: conflicting server name "gitlab.magnas.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
2022/08/02 10:16:56 [warn] 3494210#0: conflicting server name "gitlab.magnas.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
2022/08/02 10:24:13 [warn] 3495595#0: conflicting server name "gitlab.magnas.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2022/08/02 10:24:13 [warn] 3495595#0: conflicting server name "gitlab.magnas.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
2022/08/02 11:31:36 [warn] 3504813#0: conflicting server name "gitlab.magnas.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2022/08/02 11:31:36 [warn] 3504813#0: conflicting server name "gitlab.magnas.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
2022/08/02 11:36:57 [warn] 3506143#0: conflicting server name "gitlab.magnas.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2022/08/02 11:36:57 [warn] 3506143#0: conflicting server name "gitlab.magnas.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
2022/08/02 11:37:02 [warn] 3506221#0: conflicting server name "gitlab.magnas.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2022/08/02 11:37:02 [warn] 3506221#0: conflicting server name "gitlab.magnas.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
```

***on Server hosting Gitlab-runner (RHEL 9)***

**/etc/gitlab-runner/conf.toml**

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "rhel-runner-2"
  url = "https://gitlab.magnas.com"
  token = "rxF8jJtMTJdBgayB-Vbe"
  tls-cert-file = "/etc/gitlab-runner/certs/gitlab.magnas.com.crt"
  tls-key-file = "/etc/gitlab-runner/certs/gitlab.magnas.com.key"
  executor = "docker"
  clone_url = "http://10.30.36.240"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    insecure = true
    image = "ruby:2.7"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

**/etc/docker/daemon.json**

I was getting HTTPS error *"Unknown Certificate"* so i found a workaround and added this file.

```
{"insecure-registries" : ["gitlab.magnas.com:80"]}
```

**/etc/default/docker**

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--config-file=/etc/docker/daemon.json"
```

What troubleshooting steps are yet to be taken? Any help is well much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From logs that you've provided, it looks like that SSL certificate is not properly configured on your Gitlab instance.

First thing I would try is to setup let's encrypt SSL certificate instead of your `gitlab.magnas.com` certificate just to get your CI/CD pipeline to work properly without any workaround. See the documentation [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/ssl.html). Gitlab has a nice out-of-the-box support for let's encrypt certificates.

From my opinion, let's encrypt SSL cert is good solution for self-hosted Gitlab instance behind VPN.

*Just to mention, I had a similar problem with custom SSL certificate on Gitlab instance. The problem was that my `/etc/gitlab-runner/certs/custom.crt` was missing root CA certificates. This file needs to contain your certificate +  root CA certificates.*

Hope this would help.